# Breaking into a supply cable

Tags: power-supply, three-phase

I am just after general opinion on a situation.

We are looking to install energy monitoring at a particular location. The company does not want the mains supply switched off and we need to install our clamps onto the feeds to a 200A (3p+N) piece of equipment that is fed direct from the main DB. Installing at the DB live is not really the best option with the set up that we have.

We will need to install our equipment at a dry location with a wifi signal, as the equipment and its control panel and local isolation is outside, installing at the incoming feed of the equipment is also not possible.

One solution that an engineer came up with would be too isolate the supply, and break into the circuit somewhere inside the building, have the supply enter and exit a junction box that is exposing the individual feeds for us to clamp our meters onto. One of the contractors that work for the company has said this is incredibly bad practice and should not be done. We appreciate breaking into any feed is not ideal but we also feel installing a Junction Box/ Enclosure / isolator / Sub DB is our best option without having to expose the main panel.

What are your thoughts on this? not ideal yes. extremely bad practice and should not be done? I'm not sure id go that far....

Comment: Asking for opinions is generally forbidden on here – can you rephrase your question to not ask for thoughts and for opinions, but for technical arguments?

Comment: This is more of a building code and legal question than an electronics question. Although the site is headlined "Electrical Engineering", it does mostly [focus](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on small electronics, not how to rewire a building. Although I can't find anything that says your question *isn't* allowed here, you might not get a good answer.

Comment: Electricians familiar with building codes are more likely to hang out on [DIY](https://diy.stackexchange.com)